# Show timezone associated with timestamp in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My CRT_TMSTMP field in my Oracle table is a timestamp type field.

I am looking to determine the timezone associated with this field's values as it does not display in my SQL Developer client.

From my research it seems to_char() is not sufficient so I'm wondering what I can do to display this timezone in a query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [`TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00203) doesn't contain any time zone information. The documentation says "It contains fractional seconds but does not have a time zone", but it seems to implicitly be in the same time zone as the database server.

You would need your column to be [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00204) or [`TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00205) to store and retrieve a time zone linked to the value.

If you did have a column of one of those types then you could use the [`TZR` date format model element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079) (or `TZD`, `TZH` and/or `TZM`):

```
select to_char(CRT_TMSTMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR') from ...
```

But if you try that with a plain `TIMESTAMP` it will just report the server time zone. (I thought it errored, but apparently not).

As a demo:

```
create table t42 (CRT_TMSTMP timestamp,
  CRT_TMSTMP_TZ timestamp with time zone,
  CRT_TMSTMP_LTZ timestamp with local time zone);

insert into t42 values (current_timestamp,
  current_timestamp at time zone 'AMERICA/NEW_YORK',
  current_timestamp at time zone 'AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES');

select to_char(CRT_TMSTMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR') as ts,
  to_char(CRT_TMSTMP_TZ, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR') as ts_tz,
  to_char(CRT_TMSTMP_LTZ, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR') as ts_ltz
from t42;

TS                                                             TS_TZ                                                          TS_LTZ                                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------
2014-07-17 17:09:36.673 +00:00                                 2014-07-17 12:09:36.673 AMERICA/NEW_YORK                       2014-07-17 17:09:36.673 EUROPE/LONDON
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd313/2).